# Flutter FlatButton inner space

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flatbutton

In one of my flutter application, have a FlatButton like following

```
FlatButton(
   child: Text("Forgot ist ?",
       style: TextStyle(color: Color.fromRGBO(107, 106, 106, 1),fontFamily: 'ActoBook'),
       textAlign: TextAlign.left
   ),

   materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
   splashColor: Colors.transparent,  
   highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
   shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
      side: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
   ),
   onPressed: (){
       Navigator.pushReplacement(context, new MaterialPageRoute( builder: (context) => LoginPage()),);
  },
)
```

How to make the text of the button to be align at right ? Currently it is centered with equal space at left and right.

Currently  showing like this

```
+-----------------+
|   Button Text   |
+-----------------+
```

I am trying to make it like

```
+-----------------+
|      Button Text|
+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work perfectly, check it out.

```
FlatButton(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        color: Colors.blue,
        // wrap the text in a container and give it a specified width
        child: Container(
          width: 100,
          child: Text(
            "Forgot ist ?",
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Color.fromRGBO(107, 106, 106, 1),
              fontFamily: 'ActoBook',
            ),
            // set the alignment of the text to TextAlign.end
            textAlign: TextAlign.end,
          ),
        ),
        materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
        splashColor: Colors.transparent,
        highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
          side: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
        ),
        onPressed: () {
        Navigator.pushReplacement(context, new MaterialPageRoute( builder: (context) => LoginPage()),);
        },
      )),
```

This code above gives the below output:
[image: This is the output]

Answer (score 1):

Your currently can't use the `Text` class `textAlign` property to fix this issue because a `Text` inside a `FlatButton` takes up minimum amount of space. Therefore, that property will do nothing. You need to set a space to be taken by the text widget. Here's a solution:

```
FlatButton(
          materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
          splashColor: Colors.transparent,  
          highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
            side: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
          ),
          onPressed: (){
            Navigator.pushReplacement(context, new MaterialPageRoute( builder: (context) => LoginPage()));
          },
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
            width: 100, // choose your width
            child: Text("Forgot ist ?",
              style: TextStyle(color: Color.fromRGBO(107, 106, 106, 1),fontFamily: 'ActoBook'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: that is not working but then I tried this, its working. Any min width attribute set by default ? child: Text("       Forgot it ?",

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. Did my solution work or not? I ran it in my emulator and it worked for me.